# Why so many different ways to start a ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

I am evaluation ArangoDB and figured there are at least 3 ways to start the DB.

1. arangosh
2. arangod
3. arangodb
4. arangocli - this one would fall into a different category

This is all very confusing, can someone provide visibility about the different options and what is the best way to start the engine.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not different ways to start Arango. These are different tools that can be used with Arango

[arangosh](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangosh.html) is a shell tool that an be used to administer the DB as well as running ad-hoc queries. It does not start a server, it only starts the shell that connects to a server

[arangod](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangod.html): This is the deamon that runs when you start Arangodb. In fact,  to start the server you usually run (at least on Mac)  `/usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/3.4.0/sbin/arangod`

[arangodb](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/installation-mac-osx.html): This is the db install package. For example, in the Mac you would run `brew install arangodb` to install arangodb on your machine

arangocli: This is simply a cli tool to run ad-hoc queries.

Comment: I start the db with `arangodb --starter.local --starter.port=8529 start`. don't understand the difference with arangod

Comment: sorry can't grant you this answer. What is the difference between arangodb and arangod ? --help exposes tons of parameters.

Comment: `arangodb` is the _starter_, a tool that helps you to deploy the different database services in a more convenient way. Instead of launching `dbserver`, `coordinator` and `agent` with 3 different commands, the starter does that with just one.

Answer (score 0):

`arangod` starts a single ArangoDB server, which is sufficient to run a Single Instance deployment. To run more complex deployments (e.g. Cluster, Active Failover) multiple `arangod` processes are required.

For example a Cluster with 3 agents, 2 dbservers and 2 coordinators requires 8 `arangod` processes in total. More can be found in the [Cluster - Manual Start](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/deployment-cluster-manual-start.html#local-tests) documentation.

In order to simplify the deployment it is recommended to use the `arangodb` starter tool. The execution of `arangodb` initializes an `arangod` process for each dbserver, coordinator and agent. E.g. using `arangodb --starter.local` to start a local 3 node cluster starts 9 `arangod` processes internally: 3 dbservers, 3 coordinators and 3 agents. The running `arangod` processes can be checked with `ps auxw | grep arangod`.

An exemplary output can be seen below:

```
ps auxw | grep arangod
max       8099  1.9  0.1 114712  8736 pts/0    Sl+  14:47   0:00 arangodb --starter.local
max       8118  3.9  2.5 635016 203736 pts/0   Sl+  14:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/arangod -c /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/agent8551/arangod.conf --database.directory /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/agent8551/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/agent8551/apps --log.file /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/agent8551/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --javascript.copy-installation true --agency.activate true --agency.my-address tcp://localhost:8551 --agency.size 3 --agency.supervision true --foxx.queues false --server.statistics false --agency.endpoint tcp://localhost:8531 --agency.endpoint tcp://localhost:8541
max       8165 10.5  2.6 676548 215908 pts/0   Sl+  14:47   0:01 /usr/sbin/arangod -c /home/max/Documents/starter/test/agent8531/arangod.conf --database.directory /home/max/Documents/starter/test/agent8531/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /home/max/Documents/starter/test/agent8531/apps --log.file /home/max/Documents/starter/test/agent8531/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --javascript.copy-installation true --agency.activate true --agency.my-address tcp://localhost:8531 --agency.size 3 --agency.supervision true --foxx.queues false --server.statistics false --agency.endpoint tcp://localhost:8541 --agency.endpoint tcp://localhost:8551
max       8168  5.4  2.6 705236 216828 pts/0   Sl+  14:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/arangod -c /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/dbserver8550/arangod.conf --database.directory /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/dbserver8550/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/dbserver8550/apps --log.file /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/dbserver8550/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --javascript.copy-installation true --cluster.my-address tcp://localhost:8550 --cluster.my-role PRIMARY --foxx.queues false --server.statistics true --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8541 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8551
max       8171  4.8  2.5 641160 204968 pts/0   Sl+  14:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/arangod -c /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/agent8541/arangod.conf --database.directory /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/agent8541/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/agent8541/apps --log.file /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/agent8541/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --javascript.copy-installation true --agency.activate true --agency.my-address tcp://localhost:8541 --agency.size 3 --agency.supervision true --foxx.queues false --server.statistics false --agency.endpoint tcp://localhost:8531 --agency.endpoint tcp://localhost:8551
max       8302  6.4  2.6 696532 216668 pts/0   Sl+  14:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/arangod -c /home/max/Documents/starter/test/dbserver8530/arangod.conf --database.directory /home/max/Documents/starter/test/dbserver8530/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /home/max/Documents/starter/test/dbserver8530/apps --log.file /home/max/Documents/starter/test/dbserver8530/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --javascript.copy-installation true --cluster.my-address tcp://localhost:8530 --cluster.my-role PRIMARY --foxx.queues false --server.statistics true --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8541 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8551
max       8304 26.7  2.4 744684 199052 pts/0   Sl+  14:47   0:02 /usr/sbin/arangod -c /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/coordinator8549/arangod.conf --database.directory /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/coordinator8549/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/coordinator8549/apps --log.file /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-2/coordinator8549/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --javascript.copy-installation true --cluster.my-address tcp://localhost:8549 --cluster.my-role COORDINATOR --foxx.queues true --server.statistics true --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8541 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8551
max       8306  5.8  2.6 711380 215200 pts/0   Sl+  14:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/arangod -c /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/dbserver8540/arangod.conf --database.directory /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/dbserver8540/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/dbserver8540/apps --log.file /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/dbserver8540/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --javascript.copy-installation true --cluster.my-address tcp://localhost:8540 --cluster.my-role PRIMARY --foxx.queues false --server.statistics true --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8541 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8551
max       8318 27.5  2.5 760064 202456 pts/0   Sl+  14:47   0:02 /usr/sbin/arangod -c /home/max/Documents/starter/test/coordinator8529/arangod.conf --database.directory /home/max/Documents/starter/test/coordinator8529/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /home/max/Documents/starter/test/coordinator8529/apps --log.file /home/max/Documents/starter/test/coordinator8529/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --javascript.copy-installation true --cluster.my-address tcp://localhost:8529 --cluster.my-role COORDINATOR --foxx.queues true --server.statistics true --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8541 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8551
max       8321 32.8  2.5 764160 202212 pts/0   Sl+  14:47   0:02 /usr/sbin/arangod -c /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/coordinator8539/arangod.conf --database.directory /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/coordinator8539/data --javascript.startup-directory /usr/share/arangodb3/js --javascript.app-path /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/coordinator8539/apps --log.file /home/max/Documents/starter/test/local-slave-1/coordinator8539/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --javascript.copy-installation true --cluster.my-address tcp://localhost:8539 --cluster.my-role COORDINATOR --foxx.queues true --server.statistics true --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8541 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://localhost:8551
```

When specifying an option with the starter `arangodb` as `--server.storage-engine rocksdb`, this option is passed to all the starter's `arangod` processes.

A detailed overview for various deployment modes can be found in the documentation's [Deployment](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/deployment.html) chapter.